# Execution order of System.Drawing.Graphics based List<Action>

Tags: c#, list, action, system.drawing.graphics

It's my first time posting here so apologies in advance if I get the code formatting wrong. I'm coding a simple GDI+ renderer class in C#. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public interface IRenderer
{
    void Begin();
    void ClearFrame(byte R, byte G, byte B);
    byte[] End();

}

public class RendererGDI : IRenderer
{
    List<Action> renderFunctions;
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(256,256);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

    public RendererGDI()
    {
        renderFunctions = new List<Action>();
    }

    void Begin()
    {
        renderFunctions.Clear();
    }

    void ClearFrame(byte R, byte G, byte B)
    {           
        renderFunctions.Add(() => g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255, R,G,B)));
    }

    byte[] End()
    {
        foreach (Action func in renderFunctions)
            func();
    }
}
```

The End() function isn't fully implemented yet but I'm wondering if this is the correct way to store System.Drawing.Graphics operations and *only* have them execute inside the End() function?

Thanks very much for your time and help.

Craig.

Comment: Yes this would work, just remember to implement the IDisposable pattern, or to clean up all your resources in the end method.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Will you be always drawing on a `256x256` Bitmap? Meaning, what is that pre-built Bitmap as a Field doing there? You should have means to *inherit* a Graphics object from a source unknown until run-time. Or provide a constructor/method/property that sets the Graphics object or a Bitmap, or creates one using some parameters. A List of Actions is used quite often when drawing shapes or other sequences of graphic objects, you just need to make you class more *generic*.

Comment: @CraigBerry Consider using `Action<Graphics>` as signature for the renderer function: `List<Action<Graphics>> renderFunctions`. You could then pass the class private `Graphics` instance when you call it inside the `End()` function, making the `Graphics` instance accessible to use within the renderer functions.

Comment: Both fantastic suggestions. Yeah the 256x256 Bitmap was just put in there for a quick example. I am making the recommended changes now. Thanks again guys!